# Publishing: Is working at home perceived as unprofessional?

Tags: job-search, publishability

I've done research work entirely at home, it is completely unrelated to my thesis. I am going to publish it in some journal.

Although I am aware that I should not use my affiliation, and it is possible to publish without it, I am unsure about if it would turn into a disadvantage in the following sense: 1) Chances to be accepted for publishing (In real world!). 2) Perceived value of the work (for example, for future opportunities to obtain a post-doc position).

Also, the work could not be done in the same way, if someone close to me has not lent me his personal computer  (which is far more powerful than mine, but a regular PC) for few days. Does it look unprofessional to add acknowledgement to "Mr. X" (instead an institution) for providing the computational resources? Considering that, no unusual computational resources are needed (an ~400/500 USD PC in US), in a field where most first world research groups have very high computational power.

I know how it should be in theory, but I am looking for sincere answers about how  (in real world) the worldwide scientific community perceive about it, for both, chances of publication and future jobs. Any interesting consideration that I did not notice is welcome.

**Edit:**
Currently I am doing my PhD in a research institute which depends on one of the more recognized universities of my country. I have already published using this affiliation and using it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Are you a student, postdoc, or staff (faculty or professional research staff)?

Comment: @BillBarth , Thanks for reply. I edited the answer for clarification.

Comment: "I am aware that I should not use my affiliation" - shouldn't you? I'd have qualms listing, say, a commercial employer unrelated to any research as my affiliation in a paper on research conducted entirely in my spare time. But if your affiliation is a university department, it could well be justifiable to list it, if only because the daily work there gives you the motivation and operational skills to conduct research and write a paper. Or, maybe expressed in a more succinct way: Once your job is being part of the research world, the boundaries between on-duty and off-duty get *very* blurry ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I'd like to see that comment turned into an answer I could upvote.

Comment: @BillBarth: I would post it as an answer, but it wouldn't be fitting for this question.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why one would not use their normal professional affiliation for the work.

Comment: @JonCuster: To some extent, this is touched upon in [another question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38271/what-should-someone-who-works-at-a-tech-company-that-isnt-associated-with-the-w/38306).

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions here, some of which are duplicates or near duplicates to existing questions. Can you please browse the [tag:independent-researcher] tag and reduce your question to one question?

Comment: @JonCuster , Many factors. I had a lot of difficulties in publishing previously at "work" (lack of minimal resources, or lack of conditions to send a manuscript) that forced me to work at home in insane extra time (on unrelated things) to stay in the system. Also, I am not a formal worker even if my production does not belong to me. I found more difficult to find reasons to use affiliation.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I found questions and the corresponding answers both from an ideal/theoretical/legal view point. I wish to know about how it works in real life.

Answer (score 10):

No one will know that you are unaffiliated since you are free to put your research institute as an affiliation. Your institute might even be upset if you don't since you did this work while in their employment even if your contract doesn't give them rights to it if done on your own time at home using equipment that does not belong to them. If you put them as your affiliation, someone will eventually notice and may come asking questions. As such, it would probably be best to show this work to your employer through your current line manager/PhD supervisor and ask for their advice. It's likely that with some help you and your advisor will be able to publish this article together. This is how it works in the "real" world.

My favorite publication of my own was mostly done at home and in notebooks I bought myself while a student. I eventually passed it by my PhD advisor, he made some edits and suggested some changes, helped rewrite the introduction and conclusions, checked the math, and we eventually published a paper together. It was a very satisfying way to bring my side-project to a close. The material never even appeared in my dissertation (as I didn't do a so-called stapler thesis).

Comment: I would add: Do you spend all 40 hours/week at work, never doing unrelated things there, so that you don't consider your work from home as "home office"?

Comment: @yo', that didn't seem relevant to me. I was doing my job as a GRA and going to classes during my "at work" time, and then I was working on my side project at home and in coffee shops when not "at work". I assume the same from OP.

Comment: Ah ok. Well, it seems relevant to me because I can surely say that I spent less time at work, working from whereever I was at that time, including home, holidays, ...

Comment: @yo', I didn't take this as a "may I do my job from home" question but more as a "may I have side projects and label myself as an independent researcher while a student" question. I think the answer to the former is yes, and the latter is also "yes, but there's no need to do so".

Comment: Thank you. I clearly understand your point, and I followed this line of thought in the past. As consequence, the publication had a delay of more than one year, as once invited my advisor to sing on the manuscript I can't move freely. The manuscript was edited. Because of my position I had to accept the changes (cosmetics that supposed to say exactly the same, but to my  eyes many changes induced subtle conceptual mistakes). The final result was a paper that I would strong criticize (if it was not mine ;-)), and a non exclusive authorship. That would be very valuable for a future position.

Comment: That said. It is not an option to me, as I need soon make my CV grows. There have been a lot of things that do not depends on me that prevent me to have more published papers. The only way I found to publish papers fast is doing it in spare time. It is very stressful add 50-60 hours a week during months because of that. It is not about "I whish to involve myself in other project". It is publish or die. That is why my first interest is the external perception about the professionalism.

Comment: @user1420303, I haven't been on an academic hiring committee, but I don't find that my field values sole authorship. Is that a clear need in your field? Also, unless your advisor is trying to take the priority author position on the article (which is highly field-dependent and may not exist), you can probably get them to work a little faster to get the paper out, especially if it's nearly done.

Comment: _Because of my position I had to accept the changes_ — [citation needed]  Because of your position as **coauthor**, you had every right to object to changes by your other coauthor(s).

Comment: @BillBarth  Not a clear need, but I think that for someone that will decide to get an employer, it is more reliable to be"The one who invented method X", because it assures that this person has all the capabilities needed and the complete understanding of the work. 
Last time, the paper was already done(all by myself at home), in every aspect (from the original idea to the manuscript writing), but it took many months to be read (just 1 second to sign as author). I didn't win anything being generous, just the need of working 100 hours a week. If I get nothing from Y,why include Y again at all?

Comment: @JeffE It is not about right, it is about power. I had the right of publish it by myself. I did everything, at home, far away from the scope of my thesis and my advisor field of expertise, with my personal resources in my spare time.
I objected many many changes. Every one of the first objections (let say 10-15) were very well received. Then, not so well... Then I noticed that I should stop.

Comment: @user1420303, I don't think that what you want to do will be perceived as anything by any community. If you are listed in the priority author slot for your community (first, last, etc), then you will also gain the prestige for the method. Most communities are aware of this practice.