# For paper based on thesis, should I list my university as affiliation or the name of the company I currently work for?

Tags: affiliation

I am currently writing a paper for the thesis work I did last year along with my advisors. (I successfully graduated last year and currently work in a software company.) I am confused regarding what organization I should  mention in the author's section. Should I mention my university name since I completed my thesis work when I was a university student or the name of the company I currently work for?

Comment: The way I have seen it: put your current company as an affiliation and add a note saying that the work has been done while you are attending the  university.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [*What should someone who works at a tech company that isn't associated with the work list as affiliation?*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38271/what-should-someone-who-works-at-a-tech-company-that-isnt-associated-with-the-w/38284)?

Comment: Was the writing up done on company time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will take a somewhat different view from @jakebeal's answer.

The primary question is: **when did you work on the paper**? Did you do all of the work while you were a thesis student, and then the paper has slowly made its way through the system? Or did you actively work on it *as part of your new job*? Did you use institutional resources from your new position to do any part of the paper?

If the answer to the latter is *no*, then you should only list the old institution in the actual affiliations, and then list your new job as a "present address", if you so choose. If you worked on the paper as part of your new job (beyond rote submission and minor edits), then you should list both workplaces as "active" affiliations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done all the work during my thesis and before I joined my employer. However, I started writing the paper while I was in new position but never used any of my employer's resources for the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is some ambiguity here, particularly since it sounds like you have headed into a non-research industrial job.

If you were in a research-oriented position, you would probably want to put down your current affiliation as your organization, and possibly the university as a secondary affiliation (some publication venues allow multiple affiliations).

If this paper is instead from a phase of your life that you are setting behind you as you depart the research community, however, it's entirely reasonable to leave your current non-research company out of it and simply claim your old university as the relevant affiliation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a latter case as I have departed from research community into non-research industrial job

Comment: @vivek Then I would say you should definitely list your old university affiliation.  This paper is the closing of that chapter.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in the same situation, I used my current affiliation with a footnote "work performed while at ..." (my previous affiliation).

However, you need to ask your employer whether they accept using your current affiliation. In certain cases, they might ask to read/approve the paper.