# On conference abstract based on my research lab job, not university where I am currently an undergraduate, should I include university affiliation?

Tags: conference, affiliation

I am an undergraduate student working at a National research institute (I call it NatLab), not my University (Acme U).

On a proposed abstract for a conference which one of my coworkers will be presenting our work, my name is tentatively listed along with NatLab, but not Acme U.

Should I ask to also include Acme U in the affiliations?

EDIT: The reason that I suggested that my question question is related to, but not identical to the link below is that there are a few subtle differences between my question and the link.

First, I am still considered to be a student at my University while working for Natlab, and my university is associated with Natlab (they collaborate heavily, and I believe they co-fund Natlab).

The second is that I will be applying to graduate school at my Acme U (among other places), and I am hoping to avoid stepping on any toes.

Having said that, I believe I will still lean towards the answer provided in the link, and I do think it encompasses what I need, but if anyone has any other opinions, I would be happy to hear them.

Possibly related: [For paper based on thesis, should I list my university as affiliation or the name of the company I currently work for?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/70800/for-paper-based-on-thesis-should-i-list-my-university-as-affiliation-or-the-nam)

Comment: I think aeismail's answer from the linked question applies fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually people include their new institution under "current address" on papers, and I think you could do the same for abstracts & posters.

So you can ask them to list you under Acme U and include Natlab as your new address.