# Paper Authorship / Commercial?

Tags: publications, affiliation

When my co-founder and I were creating our project (with a scientific background), we always listed our universities as our affiliation, or we listed ourselves as the Co-Founders of the project with an e-mail. For the last two years or so, my co-founder has worked at a technology company in the UK, while I am still on my PhD in the US.

Now, if we author a paper, is it okay to list my university and his work affiliation (the company)? Formally, this would be correct. However, he does not work on our stuff during work hours but only in his freetime and at home.

If we do list the two affiliations (university me, company him), does it imply that the paper has a commercial touch? His employer is okay with it.

Would this setup complicate creating a startup from now on?

Comment: Given that your friend's employer gave the OK, see especially [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/38284/11365).

Comment: I may be misreading the question but I think it's a slightly different situation; in the linked question the co-author was at the company all along, whereas in this case the project started while the co-author was at the university. Suggested answer: if the bulk of the work was conducted while he was at the university normally you would give his university affiliation plus "current address: [company address]". Depending on the project (and the university), the university could be unhappy with an implied transfer of IP to a company for work done during university employment.

Comment: (Can't currently post this as an answer since the question has been marked as a duplicate; will fix this if it's reopened...)