# Adding affiliation at the proof stage

Tags: publications, affiliation

I have a paper to which I am 3rd author from my previous postdoc, and recently I got another postdoc in another institution. Is it fair and ok to add the new affiliation now, at the proof stage?

Comment: I suppose this question is best directed at the assigned editor, dont you think?

Comment: Related question: [*What should someone who works at a tech company that isn't associated with the work list as affiliation?*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38271/what-should-someone-who-works-at-a-tech-company-that-isnt-associated-with-the-w/38306). On crucial (possibly unanswered) question in this regard is whether the affiliation is a certain form of giving credit, or rather an indication of how the author can be contacted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it fair and ok to add the new affiliation now, at the proof stage?

Yes. You could insert a footnote saying that the research feeding into the paper was carried out and completed while you were affiliated with university -1 in their lab 'so and so'.

This way, everybody is happy, and you're transparent about your whereabouts.